# get emails (v3) for the shared email box in the logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I want to process shared box emails once in a day by logic app. I tried using Get emails(v3) and when I am trying to login into shared box with email then it connects to my email id as shared mail box has email id but user account is linked / given permissions by the user how have access to it.

I am able to view my emails by Get emails (V3) action. how can I view Inbox by Get emails V3 action on shared email box.

I do not want to process email immediately like in "when a new email arrives in a shared mailbox"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Yes you can add an recurrence step before the step of when a new email arrives in a shared mailbox as below:

Fisrtly, add recurrence trigger as below for 1 day as below:

[image]

then click on get mails action as below:

[image]

or you can use the below action:

[image]

By using this we can get the unread messages on a given particular day.

Comment: I want to use Search Query on the emails which is only possible in "get emails(v3)" not in shared email box. so how can I connect shared main box by get emails action . And shared inbox only work when email is unread. In my case I want to process emails based on time.

Comment: and new email arrives in  a shared mailbox only triggers when action identify new email after recurrence also.

Comment: AFAIK, you can do with "when a new mail arrives in a shared mailbox" and because it is a shared mailbox you need to have the access permission from other person.